# how i can installing rabbitmq on ubuntu container?

Tags: docker-compose, rabbitmq, dockerfile, ubuntu-18.04

i have run ubuntu container and install rabbitmq inside it, how i can access the rabbitmq from internet ?

i try adding port with "-p 15672:15672" but still cant access it

```
    [dephi@boolatnya.xyz]$ docker run -dit -p 15672:15672 ubuntu:latest --name ubuntu-rab
    [dephi@boolatnya.xyz]$ docker exec -it ubuntu-rab /bin/bash
    # apt upgrade
    # apt-get install rabbitmq-server -y
    # service rabbitmq-server start
```

when i access from myippublic:15672 it cant be reached, it should show rabbitmq login page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- RabbitMQ is listening on port 5672 after you start the `rabbitmq-server`.
- Management UI [listens on port 15672](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#usage-ui)
- You need to [enable](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#getting-started) management plugin before you can access it. Try to run this inside the container and check if you have access to the login page:

`rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management`